# Quel est le sens de « voter » utilisé de façon transitive ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Que signifie exactement « voter quelque chose » ? Je connais les sens de *voter contre quelque chose* et *voter pour quelque chose*.

À [*voter*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voter) dans le Wiktionnaire on trouve :

> 1. Exprimer son choix, sa préférence lors d’une votation.
> 2. (Transitif) Adopter par un vote.

Est-ce que, sans préposition, « voter quelque chose » signifie la même chose que « voter pour quelque chose » ? En anglais, on dit communément « vote against/for something » et pas « to vote something ».
En français, Ngrams [révèle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voter+la+r%C3%A9forme%2Cvoter+contre+la+r%C3%A9forme%2Cvoter+pour+la+r%C3%A9forme&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoter%20la%20r%C3%A9forme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoter%20contre%20la%20r%C3%A9forme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1) le contraire.

Comment: La définition que tu cites, « adopter par un vote », ne te conviens pas ?

Comment: Ton ngram ne peut pas être significatif car restreint à « réforme » et à l'infinitif du verbe. Une recherche sur un moteur de recherches en variant les temps serait certainement plus significative.

Comment: You **can** "vote something" in English!

Comment: [Examples](https://goo.gl/0gJSbD) supporting @Laure's observation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En français :

1. On vote **pour** ou **contre** quelqu'un /un parti /une loi
   (tu trouveras de nombreux exemples en faisant une recherche "vais voter pour" "vais voter contre" dans un moteur de recherches).

   - de façon elliptique on peut dire :  « Je vais voter untel /tel parti »  pour signifier qu'on « va voter **pour** ».
2. Les députés peuvent « voter une loi », le sens est différent selon le temps employé :

   - « [Les députés vont voter la loi](http://www.lepoint.fr/societe/logement-les-deputes-vont-voter-la-loi-duflot-17-09-2013-1731785_23.php) .... » : la loi va être présentée à l'Assemblée et les députés vont s'exprimer pour ou contre. Ici voter veut dire « s'exprimer ».
   - « [Les députés ont voté la loi](http://www.toulouse7.com/2013/11/20/les-deputes-ont-vote-la-loi-sur-le-non-cumul-des-mandats/)... » : la loi a été présentée et la majorité de l'Assemblée a voté pour (la loi est adoptée). Ici « voté » veut dire « voté pour » de façon elliptique.

Le sens 1 ci-dessus est exactement le même qu'en anglais - y compris [l'emploi transitif](http://www.democraticstuff.com/common/images/products/large/BT12048-2.jpg) de *to vote*.

Comment: Le sens 2 aussi, but with the substitution of "bill" (projet de loi) for "loi" (a law is a bill that has already been voted up and signed into law) and the addition of "up" or "down". It is probably more common to say "vote down a bill" than "vote a bill down", in the US at least. And probably even more common is the past tense: "The XYZ bill was voted down."

Answer (score 2):

Dans le TLF à l'entrée [*Emploi transitif*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voter) on trouve :

> B. − Empl. trans. 
>   1. Se prononcer par son vote en faveur de; décider, adopter par un vote majoritaire. 
>  a) Voter qqc.Voter un impôt, un projet de loi, une
>   motion; voter le budget, des crédits. Dans les « pays d'états »,
>   c'est-à-dire dans les provinces qui votaient elles-mêmes leurs
>   contributions, les assemblées et les Parlements résistèrent
>   (Bainville, Hist. Fr., t. 1, 1924, p. 297).V. confiance B 2 ex. de
>   Joffre. − [P. méton. de l'obj.] Voter un tronçon de route. ,,Voter les
>   crédits nécessaires à la construction d'un tronçon de route`` (Rob.
>   1985). 
>  b) Voter qqc. à qqn.Les Assemblées feraient mieux de ne pas
>   nous voter tant d'habits, d'argent, de munitions, et de nous en donner
>   (Balzac, Chouans, 1829, p. 35).
>  c) Voter que.Ce n'est pas par hasard
>   que les massacres du 2 septembre (...) eurent lieu le jour même où se
>   réunissaient les électeurs parisiens du second degré, et après que, le
>   30 août, la Législative eut voté que le Conseil de la Commune devait
>   se soumettre à la légalité (Bainville, Hist. Fr., t. 2, 1924, p. 72).
>   2. P. anal., fam. Décider ensemble, se prononcer d'un commun accord en faveur de quelque chose. Tous votèrent des remercîments et des
>   félicitations à l'éminent directeur (Zola, Argent, 1891, p. 211).

Comment: Je vous suis redevable et ai plussoyé.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que « voter *pour* quelque chose » signifie qu’un individu ou un groupe de personne, ne représentant pas nécessairement une quantité suffisante pour faire adopter leur point de vue, ont pris une décision qui n’a pas force de loi.

Alors que « voter quelque chose » signifie que l’ensemble du corps électif a majoritairement voté pour une option et que celle-ci fut adoptée. En fait « voter quelque chose » ne s’emploie qu’avec l’ensemble du corps électif.

« Les communistes ont voté contre mais le Sénat a finalement voté pour. » Les communistes font partie du Sénat mais n’ont pas rassemblé assez de voix pour gagner. Donc *voter quelque chose* s’emploie lorsque cette *chose* a emporté l’élection.
… Je crois :)

Comment: Je vous suis redevable et ai plussoye.